# Javascript Promise, returning null from catch?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

In a PR I was reviewing recently, I saw this:

`const accessToken = await getAccessToken().catch(() => null);`

My question is: Is the catch doing anything here? Does it assign null to `accessToken`? Would it be different without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrow functions` have [implicit returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

In your code snippet, if `getAccessToken()` is rejected, `catch()` will be entered, `null` will be the value which gets returned to `accessToken`.

**In essence `acccessToken` could equal *(depending on the outcome)*:**

(an example access token)

`accessToken = asda8sdaewrascsac;`

**OR**

`accessToken = null;`

---

Answer (score 1):

"The `catch()` method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only." [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

So that line simply says that if an error occures while completing the promise, `() => null`, which is basically return null inside the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if there is an error not catched inside the getAccessToken, the value inside the promise will be null

```
const accessToken = await getAccessToken().catch(() => null);  //accessToken will be a promise

accessToken .then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);    // expected output: null
});
```

Comment: Won't accessToken be null, since it was `await`ed, and thus unwrapped from the Promise?